# How to skip some nested loops in delphi?

Tags: delphi, nested-loops, skip

Could anyone please help me in this topic in Delphi?

I have 5 nested "for" block loops iterating with variables k1, k2.. k5.
Another variable k must control the depth of above 5 loops. This variable is defined during run-time.

Is it possible to eliminate the execution of the k inner 'for' blocks as if they had been commented? A short listing of explaining code is here:

```
k := 2;
for k1 := 1 to 100 do begin  
   for k2 := 1 to 100 do begin  
      for k3 := 1 to 100 do begin  
         for k4 := 1 to 100 do begin {want to skip this loop}
            for k5 := 1 to 100 do begin {want to skip this loop}  
               AnywayDoThat; // must execute anyway  
            end; {k5}  
         end; {k4}  
      end;  
   end;
end;
```

Further explaining, as k equals 2, I wish to avoid execution of loops k4 and k5 (lines of code ending in curly brackets), shortening the full flow of the program. Of course, proc AnywayDoThat must execute.

I use Delphi 6.

**Edit:** Sorry for the bad wording 'eliminated'. The aim was to avoid unnecessary iterations. The trick to skip a loop by making it to execute just once is perfect. Thus, proc AnywayDoThat is reached according to k1, k2, k3 only.

Comment: Are you sure you have understood the assignment correctly?

Comment: (the evil goto statement is looking at this question)

Comment: ˋif k > 0 then for k1 := 1 to 100 do begin if k > 1 then for k2 := etc...ˋ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following trick

```
Var 
  Maxes: array [1..5] of integer;
  Eliminators: array [1..5] of integer; // they have to be of same length
begin
  SetArray(Maxes, [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]);
  SetArray(Eliminators, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);

  // Here you set K
  K := 2;  // you need to make sure K <= 5 

  // Set the Eliminators array 

  for I := 1 to K do
    begin
      Eliminators[5-I+1] := Maxes[5-I+1];
    end;

  // Now to the loops

  for k1 := 1 to Maxes[1] div Eliminators[1] do begin  
    for k2 := 1 to Maxes[2] div Eliminators[2] do begin  
      for k3 := 1 to Maxes[3] div Eliminators[3] do begin  
        for k4 := 1 to Maxes[4] div Eliminators[4] do begin 
          for k5 := 1 to Maxes[5] div Eliminators[5] do begin  
            AnywayDoThat; // must execute anyway  
          end;  
        end;   
      end;  
    end;
  end;  


end;
```

The main idea here is to skip a loop by making it to execute once. This can be further modified to make it skip any loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use recursion. This is a rather simplified example based on your code that writes the current indices into a text file (sorry, have no Delphi 6 for testing):

```
var
  F: Textfile;

procedure AnywayDoThat(const Index: array of Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Index) to High(Index) do
    Write(F, Index[I], '.');
  Writeln(F);
end;

procedure Loop(Level, MaxLevel: Integer; const Index: array of Integer);
var
  arr: array of Integer;
  I: Integer;
  L: Integer;
begin
  if Level < MaxLevel then begin
    L := Length(Index);
    SetLength(arr, L + 1);
    for I := 0 to L - 1 do begin
      arr[I] := Index[I];
    end;
    for I := 1 to 100 do begin
      arr[L] := I;
      Loop(Level + 1, MaxLevel, arr);
    end;
  end
  else begin
    AnywayDoThat(Index);
  end;
end;

procedure Main();
var
  k: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  Index: array of Integer;
begin
  AssignFile(F, 'c:\Temp\test.txt');
  Rewrite(F);
  k := 2;
  SetLength(Index, 1);
  for I := 1 to 100 do begin
    Index[0] := I;
    Loop(1, 5 - k, Index);
  end;
  Close(F);
end;
```